# Validation on field email is not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, knockout.js

I have a single page application.I need to validate my fields on client side.So i used
   knockout.js.
I have two fields on my view page i.e email and password. What i want ,when i enter incorrect format email id then move to password then it should give a validation error of email.In simple words when entered a wrong formatted email id and press tab button then i should get a validation error. I have tried 'required pattern="@"' for validation but it dont work perfectly when Ajax calling is done. So i'm planning to use jquery to validate it.

```
 HTML:-
      <p>
   <label>email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="email" name="email"  class="formElement" data-bind='value: email'
     required pattern="@" /></label></p>
     <p>
     <label>password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="password"
      name="password" class="formElement" data-bind='value: password' /></label></p>
```

test.js :-

```
     ko.validation.rules.pattern.message = 'Invalid.';
     ko.validation.configure({
     registerExtenders : true,
     messagesOnModified : true,
     insertMessages : true,
     parseInputAttributes : true,
     messageTemplate : null
});
```

You can test my code here :-
    http://jsfiddle.net/kmvgw/324/

```
     var modalViewModel= {
     email : ko.observable().extend({ // custom message
     required : {
     message : 'Please type your  email address.'
     }
     }),
      password: ko.observable()
     };
     ko.applyBindings(modalViewModel,document.getElementById('light'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var User_Email_Id = $.trim($('#User_Email_Id').val());

if (! /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(User_Email_Id)){
  //error msg
    }
```

you may try this

Answer (score 0):

here , its working :-

email : ko.observable('').extend({ // custom message
        email: true
    }),